# Is the set $\mathcal{A}$ of all matrices whose trace is $0$ nowhere dense in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R}),n \ge 2$?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, trace

> Is the set $\mathcal{A}$ of all matrices whose  trace is $0$  nowhere dense in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R}),n \ge 2$ ?

## My attempt  : my answer is False

I take $A  = \begin{bmatrix} 1& n \\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$

I know that set of all invertible matrix is  dense. You know that  my  given matrix $A$ in invertible,  so I  think statement must be false .

Am I right or wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: But your matrix doesn't represent the set of all invertible matrices. So that doesn't help. Integers are rationals and rationals are dense in the real numbers. That doesn't mean the integers are dense in the reals.

Comment: @jasmine: There are lot of comments under my answer and the user Arthur saying my answer is incorrect. Actually Arthur was misunderstanding my answer.  Also many other users are misunderstanding my answer. Thats why they downvote my answer. I also  ask my answer is whether right or wrong in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928424/trace-zero-matrices-are-nowhere-dense-in-m-n-bbbr-n%e2%89%a52-proof-verification) post and peoples are responding 'my answer is correct'. So don't confuse yourself. Kindly read again my  answer. It was correct!

Comment: @ChinnapparajR,,thanks  u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Result**: If $A$ is a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$, then $A$ is nowhere dense in $X$ if and only if  $\overline{A}^c$ is dense in $X$
>
> [For a proof, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630165/prove-that-if-a-set-is-nowhere-dense-iff-the-complement-of-the-closure-of-the-se)]

Note that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed

So, In order to prove $\mathcal{A}$ is nowhere dense in $M_n(\Bbb{R})$, we prove $\overline{\mathcal{A}}^c=\mathcal{A}^c=M_n(\Bbb{R}) \setminus \mathcal{A}$ is dense in $M_n(\Bbb{R})$

To prove $M_n(\Bbb{R}) \setminus \mathcal{A}$ is dense in $M_n(\Bbb{R})$, we prove every point of $M_n(\Bbb{R})$ is either a point of $M_n(\Bbb{R}) \setminus \mathcal{A}$ or a limit point of $M_n(\Bbb{R}) \setminus \mathcal{A}$.

Suppose $B \in M_n(\Bbb{R}) \setminus \mathcal{A}$  ,then we are done! So asume $B \notin M_n(\Bbb{R}) \setminus \mathcal{A}$. That is $B \in \mathcal{A}$. In this case we prove $B$ is a limit point of $M_n(\Bbb{R}) \setminus \mathcal{A}$

take $B=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} &\dots&a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \ &\dots&a_{2n} \\ \vdots \\a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\dots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$ with $a_{11}+\dots+a_{nn}=0$

Then consider the sequence of elements of $M_n(\Bbb{R})\setminus \mathcal{A}$ $$A_k=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}+1/k & a_{12} &\dots&a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}+1/k \ &\dots&a_{2n} \\ \vdots \\a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\dots&a_{nn}+1/k\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $A_k \rightarrow B$ and so $B$ is a limit point!

Comment: beautiful  answer......simple  and easy to understand  , thanks u @Chinnapparaj

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: The variable $n$ is fixed by the question. You should really add $1/k$ to the diagonal.

Comment: This just means it's a [perfect set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set). That's not the same as "not nowhere dense". @stupid This doesn't answer your question at all.

Comment: @Arthur Chinnapparaj is showing that the complement is dense. That is, every trace $0$ matrix is the limit of matrices with non-zero trace. This is not to say the set of $0$-trace matrices is perfect, but it isn't enough to show nowhere-density either. For example, $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes my proof base on this result: $A$ isnowhere  dense in $X$ iff $\overline{A}^c$ is dense in $X$

Comment: @TheoBandit You're right. I was too quick and thought he added $1/k$ to one entry and subtracted it from another, this making sure the entries in the sequence has trace $0$.

Comment: Why downvote?What I'm proving wrong?

Comment: @CinnapparajR Your approach would also prove that $\Bbb Q$ is nowhere dense in $\Bbb R$ (take any rational number and add $\sqrt2/k$ to it). It therefore cannot be right.

Comment: No! What I proved is $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in R iff $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}^c=\phi$ is nowhere dense in R

Comment: @TheoBendit: I prove the closure of the complement is dense not the complement . In this case the set $A$ is closed and so closure of $A$  is $A$ itself

Comment: @Arthur: Since $\mathcal{A}$ is cloesd in $M_n(R)$, so it make sense but $\Bbb{Q}$ is not closed in $\Bbb{R}$,

Comment: @Arthur: I have used [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630165/prove-that-if-a-set-is-nowhere-dense-iff-the-complement-of-the-closure-of-the-se) result

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Your proof is perfectly alright. There is nothing wrong with it, Arthur is incorrect.

Comment: @Brahadeesh This answer looked quite different initially. I am pretty certain that I was correct then (and two people seem to have agreed).

Comment: @Arthur oh is it? I only looked at the latest version and replied. If there was a mistake earlier that you had pointed out, then I apologise for misconstruing your comments.

Comment: However, it is true that the answer is correct now, as it stands. There are no errors in the logic; in particular, the proof does *not* show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 10):

Your set is closed (as it is the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}\subseteq \Bbb R$ under the continuous trace function), and it has empty interior (as any $\epsilon$-ball around a matrix with trace $0$ will contain a matrix with non-zero trace). So it is nowhere dense.

Answer (score 3):

Your set is a finite dimensional (and hence closed) proper subspace of $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ so it is nowhere dense because [every proper subspace of a normed space has empty interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/148850/144766).